# How do I write a SQL query for Cosmos DB?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Cosmos DB, and I have a question that i created the collection called student in Cosmos DB and I connected the db in my .net sdk, then how do I write a query to select all the data from the collection student??

Comment: If my answer helps you,you could mark it for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to execute SQL queries via C# code.

Using the .NET SDK:

```
private async Task<List<Student>> GetStudentsAsync()
{
    var serviceEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost:8081");
    var masterKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
    var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("databaseId", "collectionId");
    var documentClient = new DocumentClient(serviceEndpoint, masterKey);

    var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, "select * from c").AsDocumentQuery();
    var results = new List<Student>();

    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Student>());
    }

    return results;
}
```

There is also a library (which I made) which simplifies the data access and the CosmosDB querying called [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut).

Using that the same thing becomes like this:

```
private async Task<List<Student>> GetStudentsCosmonautAsync()
{
    var serviceEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost:8081");
    var masterKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
    var databaseId = "databaseId";
    var studentStore = new CosmosStore<Student>(new CosmosStoreSettings(databaseId, serviceEndpoint, masterKey));

    return await studentStore.Query("select * from c").ToListAsync();
}
```

It comes down to personal preference so I'm providing a couple of options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to sample code:

```
class QuerySample
    {
        private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static readonly string authorizationKey = "***";
        private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
        private static readonly string collectionId = "coll";

        private static DocumentClient client;

        public static async void QueryTest()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);

            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery( uri, "select * from c",
            new FeedOptions
            {
                MaxItemCount = -1,                    
                //EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
            });
            var queryAll = query.AsDocumentQuery();

            var results = new List<Student>();

        }
    }
```